# How to ouput the static library into other directory than current?

Tags: linux, static-libraries

```
Following is my directory structure

calculator
|
|---src
      (multiply.cpp sum.cpp)
|---lib

I am building a static library calc.a using following    
ar -rcs calc.a multiply.o sum.o
```

calc.a is builded in current directory.

```
I trying calc.a to be put into lib folder not in current directory (i.e. src)
```

I searched in internet and man page but couldn't find anything.
Any idea?

Comment: Better add your compiler command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the command line, the easiest way to write the library into the lib directory is to do it explicitly:

ar -rcs lib/libcalc.a multiply.o sum.o

Using a Makefile you can do more sophisticated things, but even then, it boils down to the same thing, e.g. adding the path to the front of the library name.

Since you asked for additional info on your comment, I add here a simple Makefile, which may be helpful to get you started:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=

SOURCES=src/main.cpp src/sum.cpp src/multiply.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
LIBRARY=lib/libcalc.a
EXECUTABLE=main

all: $(SOURCES) $(LIBRARY) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(LIBRARY): $(OBJECTS)
<tab>mkdir -p lib
<tab>ar -rcs $@ $<

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
<tab>$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
<tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
<tab>rm -rf main lib/ src/*.o
```

**Important:** All `<tab>`s must be replaced with real tabs, as required by the Makefile syntax!

Makefiles are very very flexible, so they can be very simple and specific to your problem, or as general and/or complex to build many libraries and binaries, based on millions and millions of source code.  I suggest you to search for Makefile documentation for more information.

As a final note, I also suggest you to rename  your library as 'libcalc.a', since the 'lib' prefix is standard in Unix.  Other similar standards apply for other environments.

Comment: while creating library if lib folder is not exist. I wanted to create and then copy into the it. which command should I use?

Comment: I just edited the answer above to include an example of Makefile that can help you get started.  That would be too large to be inserted here.

Comment: You can also make sure the `lib` directory exists just before the `ar` command: "mkdir -p lib; ar -rcs lib/libcalc.a multiply.o sum.o"